# MUI - correcting the position in select box dropdown

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI component in react js app.

I'm trying to adjust the position of dropdown menu in select component.

As the shown image, the dropdown menu is a bit moved to right. I want to move it back to the left end.

[image]

```
        <Select
            value={value}
            label={label}
            multiple={multiple}
            onChange={onChange}
            MenuProps={{
                PaperProps: {
                    sx: {
                        maxHeight: { md: 500, xs: 300 },
                        width: { xs: '100%', lg: 'unset' },
                        '&.MuiPaper-root': {
                            left: '-8px',
                        },
                    },
                },
            }}
        >
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            
        </Select>
```

I tried to move it to the left by writing '&MuiPaper-root': {left: '-8px'}, but it automatically overwrites my code as it is showned in console.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to to add `!important` flag to prevent MUI from overwriting your styles:

```
 '&.MuiPaper-root': {
    left: '-8px !important',
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I was wondering if there was any way not to use "! important"? Or there is no other way?